# C++ class member initialized twice

Tags: c++

Are there two `MyVec`'s being created? Does a temporarty, default constructed, `MyVec` exist before the assinment in `Foo`'s constructor?

```
struct Foo {

  typedef std::vector<int> MyVec;

  Foo () {

    // determine how big the vector needs to be.
    // .....

    m_vec = MyVec(12);
  }

  MyVec m_vec; 
};
```

I know I can do it using pointers.

```
struct Foo {

  typedef std::vector<int> MyVec;

  Foo () {
    m_vec = new MyVec();
  }

  ~Foo () {
    delete m_vec;
  }

  MyVec * m_vec;
};
```

But I'd like to avoid that if possible.

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention. I can't use initializer lists because I need to do stuff in the constructor before the assignment.

Comment: duplicate of 300 questions here already

Comment: @Dave I missed a key factor in the question. Can't use an initializer list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this syntax instead:

```
struct Foo {

  typedef std::vector<int> MyVec;

  Foo ()
  : m_vec(12)
  {
  }

  MyVec m_vec; 
};
```

It's called a [c++ member initialization list](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+member+initialization+list).

---

> I can't use initializer lists because I need to do stuff in the constructor before the assignment.

If you need to calculate how big the vector is, perhaps you can do that either before you call the constructor, or in a static method which you call from the constructor:

```
struct Foo {

  typedef std::vector<int> MyVec;

  Foo ()
  : m_vec(calculateVectorSize())
  {
  }

  static int calculateVectorSize()
  {
      // determine how big the vector needs to be.
      // .....
  }

  MyVec m_vec; 
};
```

If those are impossible too, then a cheaper solution than your original post is:

```
struct Foo {

  typedef std::vector<int> MyVec;

  Foo () {

    // determine how big the vector needs to be.
    // .....

    m_vec.resize(12);
  }

  MyVec m_vec; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

And yes you can avoid it:

```
Foo():
  m_vec(/*args_to_construct_m_vec*/)
{
  // body goes here
}
```

via the above syntax.

If you cannot use initializer list because you want to do work what to put into `m_vec`, another approach is to split your class.

The part of the class that needs to be initialized before `m_vec`'s size is calculated gets stuck into a parent class.  You construct it, then construct `m_vec` in the initializer list.

Note that `std::vector` default initialization is pretty damn cheap (usually "`memset`" `sizeof`( 3 pointers ) to `0`), so your concern is almost certainly misplaced.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the typedef is just telling the compiler that `MyVec` can be seen as `vector<int>` gvien that the vector library is included.

However, no actual `MyVec` is constructed yet.

Also you should try the alternative and more preferred syntax for initializing member fields.

Comment: Not true: m_vec is default-constructed by the time the constructor body is run.

Comment: @ChrisW Thanks for pointing out. I forgot there's another constructor behind scenes for `vector<int>`. Also I was a little confused. I thought the OP asked if a `MyVec` (as an object instead of a fully-defined structure) already exists. My bad :)